# How to convert Json string into NSMutableArray in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, json

```
[{
    "ID": 122,
    "Name": "Mr.A",
    "Phone": "2222"
}, {
    "ID": 3332,
    "Name": "Mr.B",
    "Phone": "3333"
}, {
    "ID": 1021,
    "Name": "Mr.C",
    "Phone": "1313"
}, {
    "ID": 2221,
    "Name": "Dinesh",
    "Phone": "103"
}]
```

I have coded like this, yet it does still not work!

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"My page"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSError *error;

NSMutableArray *json = (NSMutableArray*)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data  options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSLog(@"%@",json);
```

My Json variable cannot still get the data.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: My Json variable cannot get the data.

Comment: What error do you get in the `NSError` instance ?

Comment: JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set

Comment: Set the `allow fragments` option as suggested and insert two lines: `NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];` `NSLog(@"%@", string);` after retrieving the data to see its string representation.

Comment: It's probably not valid JSON

Comment: What's the value of `[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`? You "showed" the JSON at the beginning of your question, but from where did you get it like this?

Comment: Hoo I now get the data, but I want to put it into NSMutableArray. How can I?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@Sengvuthy Pheng,
Here's sample code:
In my ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <NSXMLParserDelegate>
```

In my ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"your url"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSXMLParser *myParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [myParser setDelegate:self];
    [myParser parse];
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser*)parser didStartElement:(NSString*)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString*)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString*)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary*)attributeDict {
    NSLog(@"didStartElement");
}

- (NSString *)nameForNode:(NSDictionary *)node inDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict {
    NSLog(@"nameforNode");
    return nil;
}

- (void)parser:(__unused NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(__unused NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(__unused NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(__unused NSString *)qName {
    NSLog(@"didEndElement");
}

- (void)parser:(__unused NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    NSLog(@"foundCharacters");
    NSLog(@"JSONdata = %@", string);
    NSData* data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSError *e;
    NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:&e];
    NSLog(@"jsonArray = %@", array);
}

- (void)parser:(__unused NSXMLParser *)parser foundCDATA:(NSData *)CDATABlock {
    NSLog(@"foundCDATA");
}

- (void)parser:(__unused NSXMLParser *)parser foundComment:(NSString *)comment {
    NSLog(@"foundComment");
}
```

Comment: I want to take the Json string to NSArray. How can I?

Answer (score 3):

Print the error. Print the data. "It doesn't work" without the slightest bit of checking?

PS. The result of that call will *never* be an NSMutableArray, so there's a crash waiting to happen. A cast doesn't make it an NSMutableArray.

Comment: The string comes from returning of my ASP.Net Web service in Json string.

Comment: My Json variable cannot get the data.

Comment: You could change options to `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers` to have `NSMutableArray`.